# I lost a letter in skyrim and I need help

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I need help. I have been playing Skyrim for quite some time, but I seem to have lost my letter from Septimus Sigmus.

Does anyone know if there’s a way I could get the letter again from the courier? Or do I have to scavenge all of Skyrim?

If it makes it any different, I’m playing on Xbox 360 and I’m level 52.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need the letter to complete the quest.

The letter is delivered to you only if you were below level 15 when you hit a certain point in [Discerning the Transmundane](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Discerning_the_Transmundane), then leveled up past that point. It just tells you you're a high enough level to return to Septimus Signus and continue the quest.

> To continue past this point, you must be level 15 or higher. If you aren't level 15 yet, giving Septimus the Lexicon will result in him dismissing you; then, you must wait until a courier delivers a letter from him to continue.

According to the [discussion page for the letter itself](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim_talk:Letter_from_Septimus_Signus), you will get a quest marker by reading the letter. However, you should be able to return to Septimus Signus' Outpost and continue the quest without it.